# ORDER BY and UNION in SQLPLUS issue

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I am giving the following error: "ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression" when I try to select id_prof using "order by" while making a union between to columns from different tables.

The command is as follows:

```
select substr(nume, 1, 1)||'.'||regexp_replace(prenume, '[aeiou]', null, 1, 0, 'i') as "Rododendron" 
from studenti 
union 
select ceil(sqrt(to_number(substr (id_prof, 2, 1))*2)) as "Fata de con" 
from profesori 
where grup_didactic = 'Lect' 
order by to_number(substr (id_prof, 2, 1)) desc;
```

The tables are in the following pictures: [FirstPicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BevI1.jpg) [SecondPicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HGoM.jpg)

I would like to have in the end two columns.

The first one should include the first letter from "nume", concatenated with '.' and "prenume" without vowels (column named "Rododendron").

In the second one I want to have the square root, rounded upper, from the double of id_prof's number (column named "Fata de con"), for everything that can be found in "profesori", where grup_didactic = 'lector' and everything is ordered desc after id_prof.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle says that you can't sort the result by column that isn't contained in the `SELECT` column list; such as in this simple Scott's schema example:

```
SQL> select ename from emp
  2  union
  3  select dname from dept
  4  order by substr(ename, 1, 3);
order by substr(ename, 1, 3)
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression
```

---

I'd say that *sorting* is the least of your problems, currently. `UNION` won't return two columns; remove `ORDER BY` and see for yourself - if you're *lucky*, you'll get a single column.

This is what you do now:

```
select col from studenti
union
select another_col from profesori
```

while you want to get

```
select col, another_col
from ...
```

`FROM` clause is tricky, as it seems that you're selecting from two different tables. Can you join them so that query looks like the second option? If not, you can always do a Cartesian product, but that will most probably be a wrong result.

It would help if you provided sample input data and explain how to get the result out of that *input*.